# CMAKE in my OpenCV 4.2.0 source code couldn't find any cuDNN installed in my machine

Tags: opencv, cudnn

I'm compiling OpenCV4.2 on Ubuntu 20.4 following this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/

I did make sure to download cudnn-11.2-linux-x64-v8.1.0.77.tgz for my CUDA 11.2, extract it, and copy all the files to the appropriate folders in /usr/local/cuda/lib64 and /usr/local/cuda/include

I run CMAKE in the /build folder of opencv source code like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=5.0 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/opencv_cuda/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include ..
```

However the output log of CMAKE shows cuDNN is NO, this is the snippet of the errors:

```
-- Could NOT find CUDNN: Found unsuitable version "..", but required is at least "7.5" (found /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so)
-- CUDA detected: 11.2
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-D_FORCE_INLINES
```

And here is the full configuration output

> ```
> - General configuration for OpenCV 4.2.0 =====================================
> --   Version control:               unknown
> -- 
> --   Extra modules:
> --     Location (extra):            /home/thomasm/opencv_contrib_self_built/modules
> --     Version control (extra):     unknown
> -- 
> --   Platform:
> --     Timestamp:                   2021-02-16T15:54:14Z
> --     Host:                        Linux 5.8.0-43-generic x86_64
> --     CMake:                       3.16.3
> --     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
> --     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
> --     Configuration:               RELEASE
> -- 
> --   CPU/HW features:
> --     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
> --       requested:                 SSE3
> --     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
> --       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
> --       SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
> --       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
> --       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
> --       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
> --       AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
> --       AVX512_SKX (6 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
> -- 
> --   C/C++:
> --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
> --     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
> --     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
> --     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
> --     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
> --     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
> --     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
> --     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
> --     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
> --     ccache:                      NO
> --     Precompiled headers:         NO
> --     Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static -lpthread dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cufft -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> --     3rdparty dependencies:
> -- 
> --   OpenCV modules:
> --     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d 
>    ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d
>    cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow
>    cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres
>     dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash
>      imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow
>     phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape
>  stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text
>     tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect
>    xphoto
> --     Disabled:                    world
> --     Disabled by dependency:      -
> --     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv java js matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
> --     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
> --     Documentation:               NO
> --     Non-free algorithms:         YES
> -- 
> --   GUI: 
> --     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
> --       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.3)
> --       GtkGlExt:                  NO
> --     VTK support:                 NO
> -- 
> --   Media I/O: 
> --     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
> --     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
> --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
> --     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
> --     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
> --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
> --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
> --     HDR:                         YES
> --     SUNRASTER:                   YES
> --     PXM:                         YES
> --     PFM:                         YES
> -- 
> --   Video I/O:
> --     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
> --     FFMPEG:                      YES
> --       avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
> --       avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
> --       avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
> --       swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
> --       avresample:                NO
> --     GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
> --     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
> -- 
> --   Parallel framework:            pthreads
> -- 
> --   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
> -- 
> --   Other third-party libraries:
> --     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
> --            at:                   /home/thomasm/opencv_self_built/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
> --     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
> --               at:                /home/thomasm/opencv_self_built/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
> --     Lapack:                      NO
> --     Eigen:                       NO
> --     Custom HAL:                  NO
> --     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
> -- 
> --   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.2, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
> --     NVIDIA GPU arch:             50
> --     NVIDIA PTX archs:
> -- 
> --   cuDNN:                         NO
> -- 
> --   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
> --     Include path:                /home/thomasm/opencv_self_built/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
> --     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
> -- 
> --   Python 3:
> --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.5)
> --     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.5)
> --     numpy:                       /home/thomasm/.local /lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include
>     (ver 1.18.5)
> --     install path:                lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8
> -- 
> --   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
> -- 
> --   Java:                          
> --     ant:                         NO
> --     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
>   /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
>     /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
> --     Java wrappers:               NO
> --     Java tests:                  NO
> -- 
> --   Install to:                    /usr/local
> ```

This is frustrating since the cmake file could detect my CUDA, but couldn't find my CUDNN

Is there any fix I can make since I'm sure a lot have encountered this error as well

Comment: The point is: did you install cudnn ? Looks like you installled cuda but not cudnn, you can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mww1-1NufIo&t=68s) how to install. In the article you shared also talking at the beginning about installing cudnn, you missed there ?

Comment: I followed the tutorial video that you showed, it took me to https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/archives/cudnn_741/cudnn-install/index.html website

I downloaded cudnn 8.1 since my CUDA ver is 11.2, I did exactly all 3 commands needed
$ sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
$ sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*

That's it for installation right ?
The files are there in the appropriate folders but it still couldn't recognize

Comment: yes carrying the files is installation

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this issue was caused by OpenCV 4.2 itself, updating to version 4.5.1, the latest as of Feburary 2021 solved the issue of not detecting cuDNN (also a reminder that OPENCV 4.5 is not compatible with gcc > 8 so downgrade your gcc to 8 and sym link it before attempting to compile )

Comment: Changing gcc version is a dangerous way on ubuntu, people who ll downgrade should be carefull. Aso it ll be better if you share the references which saying about the version compatibility.